# Criar fundo personalizado em CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout-responsivo

Estou com uma certa dificuldade em criar um fundo em CSS assim :

[image: O Objeto que quero criar]
O que eu consegui fazer foi 2 triângulos "Gambiarra", más queria que fosse um único objeto e também ficasse sempre alinhado com o logo.

Assim:

[image: Resultado Final]
Conforme a resolução da tela ele perde o alinhamento.
Não sei se é possível fazer desta forma, se não for aceito sugestões

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Muito melhor aplicar uma imagem do que quebrar a cabeça com CSS pra fazer isso, e se conseguir fazer.

Comment: Também sugiro imagem!